# To find out how many students have not taken any of three courses

Tags: probability

In a class of $200$ students, $125$ student have taken programming language course ,$85$ students have taken Data Structure ,$65$ students have taken Computer Organisation course, $50$ students have taken both programming language and Data Structure syllabus, $35$ students have taken both programming languages and Computer Organisation ,$30$ students have taken data structure and Computer Organisation. $15$ students have taken all the three courses. how many students have not taken any of the courses?

My calculation-
$50$ students have programming lang. And data struc. 
$30$ students have data struc. And computer organization
$35$ have computer organization and programming language
If we subtract $50$ students $+35$ students from $120$ who has programming language$=40$ students left
And $85-(50+30)= 5$ left
$65-(30+35)=0$ left

Number of students who have all courses$=15$
Now how to find number of students have not taken any of $3$ courses?

Comment: The easiest way is to make a Venn diagram with three circles.  Each region should get a number showing how many students have taken exactly those courses.  As you have $15$ that took all three, put $15$ in the central region.  That accounts for $15$ of the ones who took both programming language and data structure, so you put ??? in (which region).  Continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\{\text{students who took programming}\}$

$B=\{\text{students who took data structure}\}$

$C=\{\text{students who took computer organization}\}$

The number of students who have taken at least one of those three classes is described by $|A\cup B\cup C|$

Via [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), we know

$$|A\cup B\cup C| = |A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$$

The number of students who have taken *none* of those three classes is $|A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c| = |S|-|A\cup B\cup C|$

The problem statement tells you all of the numbers necessary to complete the calculations.

> $|S|=200, |A|=125, |B|=85, |C|=65, |A\cap B|=50, |A\cap C|=35, \dots$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: The formula is $|(P\cup D\cup C)'|=|U|-|P\cap D\cap C|-|P\cap D\cap C'|-|D\cap C\cap P'|-|P\cap C\cap D'|-|P\cap D'\cap C'|-|D\cap C'\cap P'|-|C\cap P'\cap D'|= 200 - 15 - ...$. Can you complete it?